# Information about $ZFC + (\neg CH)$

Tags: logic, reference-request, set-theory, nonstandard-models

$\underline{\text{Some Background}}$: A classic axiomatic system of set theory in modernity is $ZFC$. Results from modern mathematical logic guarantee the existence of statements undecidable given sufficiently complex axiom schemas like $ZFC$, such as $CH$, the continuum hypothesis. Some people then choose to study $ZFC + CH$, since it is generally perceived as more intuitive that there should be no set which is too big to be countable but is strictly smaller than $|\mathbb{R}|$.

$\underline{\text{The Question}}$: However, this does not mean there there isn't a perfectly nice model and associated set theory which has these strange sets. My question is this; what information exists about set theories with axioms $ZFC + (\neg CH)$? Does anyone know anything about this set theory, about results and theorems from this type of set theory, are people studying it, might there even be some sort of strange text book written which contains a large digression to set theories of this sort?

To me this would be something very interesting to read about, and I decided to post this question in hopes that I'm not the only one, and so that perhaps others in the future have an easier time finding a starting point for learning about these set theories if one does indeed exist.

Comment: You may be interested to hear about forcing axioms like the [proper forcing axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_forcing_axiom) and [Martin's maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_maximum).

Comment: Also note that "too big to be countable and too small to be uncountable" is provably false if we assume choice. What you probably meant to say is "too big to be countable but strictly smaller than $\mathbb R$".

Comment: I'll make the edit so that it's more clear what I mean; thanks! :)

Comment: As far as I know, most people (who have any educated opinion about the subject) believe CH is (or should be, depending on your philosophical stance) false. (Caveat: I am no set theorist, and I have little interest in truthood of CH beyond situations where it can be forced.)

Comment: I don't have enough expertise to assess it, but it seems to me that Hugh Woodin's book *The Axiom of Determinacy, Forcing Axioms, and the Non-Stationary Ideal* is highly relevant here. As he puts it in the introduction to the second edition: "The main result of this book is the identification of a canonical model in which the *Continuu Hypothesis* is false." (He changed his mind on the status of CH since then, though)

Comment: The "problem" with $\neg\mathsf{CH}$ is that it's just not very powerful: unlike $\mathsf{CH}$ it doesn't significantly sharpen our picture of things, and so the bare theory $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH}$ doesn't seem particularly useful to switch to. However, there are quite natural strengthenings of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that imply $\neg\mathsf{CH}$. For instance, while it's not clear exactly what $\mathsf{ZFC+\neg CH}$ is the "right" context for, $\mathsf{ZFC+PFA}$ is a very natural context for a wide swath of questions and happens to prove $\neg\mathsf{CH}$.

Comment: That said, there are lots of consistency results which are quite interesting and can only be witnessed by models in which the continuum hypothesis fails. For example, pretty much anything about **cardinal characteristics of the continuum** falls into this territory, such as (relatively recent and quite deep) [simultaneous separation results](https://mathoverflow.net/a/156631/8133). I don't quite think this is what you're looking for, since this is an investigation into what models of $\neg\mathsf{CH}$ *might* look like instead of *must* look like, but it is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this has been open for a number of years without much activity, I'll summarize the actionable directions given to me in the comments, and call that a sufficient answer. I'll link as much as possible below so that no one's suggestions get misattributed or forgotten.

- The user [Stefan Mesken](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/217623/stefan-mesken) suggested looking into forcing axioms (such as the [proper forcing axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_forcing_axiom) and [Martin's Maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_maximum).
- The user [Nagase](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/117698/nagase) suggested the book [The Axiom of Determinacy, Forcing Axioms, and the Non-Stationary Ideal](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110213171/html) by High Woodin, who Nagase points out states "The main result of this book is the identification of a canonical model in which the Continuum Hypothesis is false" in the introduction of the second edition.
- The user [Noah Schweber](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28111/noah-schweber) suggested looking into $\neg CH$-specific properties that arise, linking this post on [simultaneous separation results](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37188/consistency-results-separating-three-cardinal-characteristics-simultaneously/156631#156631) (as a subset of cardinal characteristics of the continuum).